# Selecting Multiple Items From List in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So given the example below with bootstrap referenced...

```html
<div class="container">
   <h2>Active Item in a List Group</h2>
   <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

It would show something like this...

[image]

By default when I click on an item from the list, it gets highlighted but as soon as I click on another item, the previously highlighted item won't be anymore and the newly clicked item gets highlighted. Only 1 is highlighted at any time. How do I make the items function like a switch or toggle? When I click on the 1st item it gets highlighted. When I click on the 2nd one it also gets highlighted. If a highlighted item gets clicked on, it loses its highlighted status. How do I do this without modifying Bootstrap? Or if it's needed to modify, how can it be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `.active` class to list group items. Since you are populating with `<a>` tags :

```
$('.list-group a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active')
})
```

Comment: not working for me...

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add the "active" class on each click to the item. You can write a simple function to do that :

**Pure JS (Vanilla) :**

First create a function :

```
 function ToggleClass(listItem) {
      listItem.classList.toggle("active");
  }
```

Then implement it :

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName(".list-group-item");

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
listItems[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>ToggleClass(listItems[i]), false);
}
```

**With JQuery**

```
              $('.list-group-item').on('click',function(e){
                //First check if the item is active.
                let isActive = $(e.target).attr('class').includes("active");

                if (!isActive) {
                //Not Active ? Add the ".active" class.
                   $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item
                } else {
                // Active ? Remove the ".active" class.
                   $(e.target).removeClass('active');;
                }
              });
```

Source : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#active-items

**EDIT**

The next answer (from @davidkonrad) suggest a more "clean way" to do that by using the build-in function of JQuery : .toggleClass(). I would also suggest to use it